# Row data from a comma-delimited field used within a select query

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to build a single select query that returns
a list of Product Type Description using `Table1` that is not
in the `ExcludedList` of `Table2`.

I have the following tables and data in SQL Server 2008.

```
Table1(nProdType INT, sProdDesc VARCHAR)

nProdType   SProdDesc
----------- --------------------
1           Pencils
2           Paper
3           Pens
4           Markers
5           Erasers
6           Crayons
7           HighLighters
8           Rulers


Table2(ClassID INT, ExcludeList VARCHAR)

ClassID     ExcludedList
----------- --------------------
100         2,3,4,8
101         1,2,5,6,7,8
102         4,5,6,7
103         1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
104         7
```

The query should return the following:

```
ClassID  nProdType  sProdDesc
-------- ---------  --------------
100      1          Pencils
100      5          Erasers
100      6          Crayons
100      7          HighLighters
101      3          Pens
101      4          Markers
102      1          Pencils
102      2          Paper
102      3          Pens
102      8          Rulers
```

..and so on..

I know how to build (and of course there are plenty solutions in SO) a function to split the comma-delimited field but they return *ALL* the rows in the table and I want it to be per record (`ClassID`) so that I can query to see what's not in the `ExcludedList`. I am trying to not code this in C# or to use a RecordSet.

Comment: Besides what you are asking, is it possible to change the tables? Because that's a quite awful design which can't have referential integrity in the excluded list. Fixing that would be the best option in the long run.

Comment: Andrew, I am in full agreement that the design is awful and unfortunately I cannot change the schema as it's part of legacy code that has to stay as is. In fact my tables above are a simplification of what the tables really look like. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CSV Splitter for this. Here is the **[DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)** function by Jeff Moden.

```
;WITH CteDelimitted AS(
    SELECT
        t.ClassID,
        nProdType = CAST(s.Item AS INT)
    FROM Table2 t
    CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.ExcludedList, ',') s
),
CteCross AS(
    SELECT
        t2.ClassID,
        t1.nProdType,
        t1.SprodDesc
    FROM Table1 t1
    CROSS JOIN(
        SELECT DISTINCT ClassID FROM Table2
    )t2

)
SELECT * 
FROM CteCross c
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM CteDelimitted
    WHERE
        ClassID = c.ClassID
        AND nProdType = c.nProdType
)
ORDER BY ClassID, nProdType
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f74af/1/0)

---

Another approach using `NOT IN`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        t2.ClassID,
        t1.nProdType,
        t1.SprodDesc
    FROM Table1 t1
    CROSS JOIN(
        SELECT DISTINCT ClassID FROM Table2
    )t2
)
SELECT *
FROM Cte c
WHERE c.nProdType NOT IN(
    SELECT CAST(s.Item AS INT)
    FROM Table2
    CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(ExcludedList, ',') s
    WHERE ClassID = c.ClassID
)
ORDER BY ClassID, nProdType
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f74af/2/0)

Comment: Thanks for the code above. Unfortunately SQL Server 2008 R2 is giving me the error "Incorrect syntax near '.'."  on the dbo.DelimitedSplit8K line. I forgot to mention that the tables are from a legacy system that used to be on SQL Server 2000 and migrated to SQL Server 2008 but remained in mode 80. Could that be the problem? Also, I cannot switch to latest mode. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, figured it out. I added a use temp; to get the mode 90 and its working. Now, what if I have a datetime field in table 2 and want to filter by a specific date?

Comment: @Leo, sorry for the delayed response. I'm glad you made it. =)

Comment: W., Thanks so much. It was both exciting and disappointing to get this up and running with your help. Exciting because it works wonderfully, disappointing because I could never have come up with this solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @Leo, you'll get there. Just take time to read and take a lot of practice. Anyway, if this solved your problem, consider accepting this answer.

Comment: One last thing I'm having issues with is putting all this in a view along with the USE TempDB which is needed to execute the mode 90 code but with a mode 80 DB...

Comment: @Leo, I've googled on how to convert the above query to be compatible with sql server 2000 (compatibility 80), but I can't find anything. I suggest you create a new question regarding this.

Comment: All is good. The query is running in production and working perfectly. Thanks again.